# Copy lines from one paragraph to another in the same file

Tags: awk, sed

I want to copy all lines under a heading until a blank line and replace all the same lines under a different heading, so starting with this:

```
[bob]
id = bob
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L

[sally]
id = sally
secret = SyBz7sBhNO7x78Uxs6ODmk2biyJL89NnJp1lmbYr

[person1]
id = foo
secret = bar

[person2]
id = foz
secret = baz
```

I want to replace the settings under [bob] to [person1] without changing any other paragraph:

```
[bob]
id = bob
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L

[sally]
id = sally
secret = SyBz7sBhNO7x78Uxs6ODmk2biyJL89NnJp1lmbYr

[person1]
id = bob
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L

[person2]
id = foz
secret = baz
```

Comment: hint: use paragraph mode in awk along with sub functions

Comment: Looks to be ini file format. Suggest using a proper syntax aware ini parser

Comment: edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve your problem. We're here to help you fix your code, not do it for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\[bob\]/{n;:a;/^$/M!{N;ba};h};/^\[person1\]/{n;:b;/^$/M!{N;bb};g}' file
```

If a line begins `[bob]`,print it and replace it with the next line.

Append further lines until an empty one, then store the collection in the hold space and print those lines as normal.

If a line begins `[person1]`, print it and replace it with the next line.

Append further lines until an empty one, then replace the pattern space by the hold space and print those lines as normal.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` using an empty `RS`, it is fairly simple:

```sh
awk -v RS= '{
   ORS = RT 
}
# save data into variable val
$1 == "[bob]" { 
   val = $0
   sub(/[^[:space:]]+/, "", val) 
}
# copy data from variable val
$1 == "[person1]" {
   sub(/\n.*/, "")
   $0 = $0 val
} 1' file
```

```
[bob]
id = bob
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L

[sally]
id = sally
secret = SyBz7sBhNO7x78Uxs6ODmk2biyJL89NnJp1lmbYr

[person1]
id = bob
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L

[person2]
id = foz
secret = baz
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, a generic ini file parser (no guarantees on completeness!). The question's requirements are implemenbted in the END section

```sh
gawk '
    BEGIN { FS = "[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*"; OFS = " = " }
    function join(start, end, sep,     result, i) {
        result = $start
        for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
            result = result sep $i
        return result
    }
    function printIni() {
        for (i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
            print "[" sections[i] "]"
            for (key in data[sections[i]]) {
                print key, data[sections[i]][key]
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
    NF == 0 {next}
    match($0, /^\[(.+)\]$/, m) {s++; sections[s] = m[1]; next}
    { data[sections[s]][$1] = join(2, NF, OFS) }

    END {
        for (key in data["person1"])
            data["person1"][key] = data["bob"][key]

        printIni()
    }
' file.ini
```

outputs

```
[bob]
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L
id = bob

[sally]
secret = SyBz7sBhNO7x78Uxs6ODmk2biyJL89NnJp1lmbYr
id = sally

[person1]
secret = 3Jj0gtYkH42G+2F02n9NPcGmI6V8bKZg2gfZCS3L
id = bob

[person2]
secret = baz
id = foz
```